# window.onload doesn't work at all

Tags: javascript, youtube

I made an extension for youtube new layout, but since yesterday (they had some issues with the layout) the extension stopped working.

It seems like it does not respond to the action **window.onload** event as I am using like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
   $('body').on('mouseenter', '#thumbnail', function() {
      console.log('test');
   }); 
};
```

For some reason every time I hover on a video thumbnail, the test is not being outputted at all. It might work once every 50 times or so.

I have jquery injected above this script as well and they are both inside the head tags. Can youtube block **window.onload** event or am I doing something completely wrong?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using the jQuery document ready function?

$(document).ready(function(){
  $('body').on('mouseenter', '#thumbnail', function() {
      console.log('test');
   }); 
};

Comment: One thing that could happen is that some other code could come along after yours and override your event handler with code like yours. Since you're using jQuery anyway, you could use a "ready" handler instead.

Comment: @Pointy I dont know if that would be any use, but there are no other onload events in the code on youtube page. @JonMayer I have tried this and I get the error `$ is not defined`

Comment: If you're getting an error that `$` is not defined, then something has messed up your import of jQuery and your code won't work anyway.

Comment: Its strange because if I call this `$(document).ready(function(){ $('body').on('mouseenter', '#thumbnail', function() { console.log('test'); }); });` from a js script which is being added inside content script, it will work just fine, but the youtube iframe API will not function